# Prevent OutputCache from caching for changes in one parameter, allow for others

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, outputcache

I'm implementing output caching in my solution and found an issue for covering this specific scenario.

There's a search action that has a few parameters, the first one is the searched text and the rest are filters, sort, offset and limit. It looks somewhat like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Search(
    string query = "",
    ushort limit = 12,
    int offset = 0,
    int filter1 = 0,
    int filter2 = 0,           
    SortObject sort = null)
{
}
```

The thing is, the filtered search without a query is used most often and I want to cache the results of that kind. However, if someone uses a text query, it will most probably be a unique one every time, so I don't see a point in caching those and wasting memory space.

I've used the following `OutputCacheAttribute` to achieve that:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByParam = "filter1;filter2;limit;offset;sort")]
```

But (as expected) it didn't work, as it completely ignores the `query` parameter and caches per change in other parameters.

What I want to achieve is to cache the results for `query` parameter being empty, while others are being changed. However, if the `query` parameter is not empty, I want the request to go always go to the code.

Is that possible to achieve with Output Cache?

Comment: Have you tried using `VaryByCustom`instead?

Comment: I've read about it, but (based on examples) it seems that it's more of a mechanism to create more cached versions based on custom strings (or browser type and version). What I need is to prevent a result being stored in cache for `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query)`, is that achievable with `VaryByCustom`?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to include more than just query. In fact, all of these are important to vary on. Consider that `OutputCache` actually caches the response, not just the queries ran inside the action, so even `sort` would require a different response, or it would have no effect on the returned view. All the others, though, are inherently tied to the query that is made, so those effect not just the view but the actual data that is returned.

Long and short, you should really just do `VaryByParam="*"` and call it a day. Anything else will cause problems.

If you're looking to cache the query itself, then you can use `MemoryCache` for that. However, again, you'll need to take into account everything but `sort` here, or the actual data will not be correct.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of it, maybe I just phrased it wrong.

VaryByParam="*" will cause OutputCache to store responses for each text query separately, which feels a bit like a memory space waste and I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: Well, you can't have it both ways. You have to vary on the query or you'll be sending the results for whatever query generated the cache, rather than the current one the user is making. Either you cache each query, or you cache none.

Comment: For what it's worth, output cache is really never used for something like a search page. Virtually every request is going to be different in some way, so it make little sense to ever cache anything. The odds that two request will be made with exactly the same query, filters, sort order, etc. is infinitesimal.

Comment: It is generally the case and in my scenario always the case for text search. However, in our application, there are some 'predefined searches', which are always a set of filters with a default limit and offset, and most probably will be the most used thing by the users. That's why I wanted to cache those, but in case of a text search always go to the code.

Comment: Then, I would suggest dropping `OutputCache` and going for just memory caching the queries you care about explicitly.